# Getting latest record on every department

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day developers!

[image: Image 1]

I have this table JOBS and i wanted to get the latest record of every department.

As you can see, there is only 2 department. The output row should be ID's # **1 and 6**

I tried using this

```
SELECT j.id, j.title, j.department_id, j.date_created
FROM JOBS j
WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM JOBS WHERE id = j.id)
GROUP BY j.department_id
```

but i'm getting the row of ID's # 1 and 3.

Please help. thank you!

Comment: Use department_id in the sub-query's WHERE clause.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY j.date_created`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution using `subquery`:

```
SELECT j.id, j.title, j.department_id, j.date_created
FROM JOBS j
WHERE (department_id, Date) IN 
    (SELECT department_id, MAX(date_created) FROM JOBS WHERE department_id = j.department_id)
```

This can also be rewritten as a `JOIN`.

Comment: This is what i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN()` :

```
SELECT j.id, j.title, j.department_id, j.date_created
FROM JOBS j
WHERE (date_created,department_id) IN (SELECT MAX(Date),department_id FROM 
                                      group by department_id)
```

Or `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM JOBS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM JOBS s
                 WHERE s.department_id = t.department_id
                   AND s.date_created > t.date_created)
```

Or with a left join:

```
SELECT t.* FROM JOBS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN JOBS s
 ON(t.department_id = s.department_id AND s.date_created > t.date_created)
WHERE s.id is null
```

Comment: The first one's sub-query may return more than 1 row. Do IN instead... As you already said.

Comment: @jarlh Typo.. as I wrote 'use in()' :P

Answer (score 1):

Using Sub Query with MAX and Inner Join

```
SELECT j.id, j.title, j.department_id, j.date_created, q.time_stamp
    FROM JOBS j
    Inner Join (
     Select id,title
              ,max(Date) as time_stamp
        From JOBS 
        Group By id, title)As q

        On j.id = q.id
    And j.date_created = q.time_stamp
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't like square brackets afaik.

Comment: Users table? Where did you find that?

Comment: @jarlh modified my mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM JOBS 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT departmen_id,MAX(date_created) as maxdate FROM JOBS
    GROUP BY department_id
) AS maxdates
ON JOBS.department_id=maxdates.department_id
AND JOBS.date_created=maxdates.maxdate
```

Comment: That answer refers to a `users` table which I have not seen any info about in the question. Hence the query will fail.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that! You're absolutely right. (Will up-vote here, and remove the other one.)

Answer (score 0):

The query you tried is invalid SQL. It is accepted by MySQL but the values it returns for expressions that do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clauses [are indeterminate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

The reason such a query does not return what you expect is simple: `GROUP BY` does not work with table row. It generates new rows. It creates groups from the rows filtered using the `WHERE` clause, using the expressions from the `GROUP BY` clause. For such each group, it computes a value for each expression present in the `SELECT` clause, each one independently from the other expressions.

In the `SELECT` clause you can use:

- the expressions that are present in the `GROUP BY` clause; each of them produces the same value for all the records from a group (because this is how the groups are created, isn't it?);
- [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) - the compute an aggregate function using all the values from the group;
- since MySQL 5.7.5: expressions that contain non-aggregated columns that are functionally dependent on the columns that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Before version 5.7.5, MySQL used to accept columns that are not functionally dependent on the expressions that appear in `GROUP BY` (your case) but it explicitly states in the documentation that the value produced for such a column is indeterminate. It is selected from the values that exist in the group but it is neither the first one, nor the last one, it's a random one.

Running such a question twice using the same input data can produce different results; this happens after the data of the tables included in the query is re-organized by MySQL for some reason (when it is moved on a different server or restored from backup, from example).

#### One of the correct ways to generate the results you need

There are several ways to get the results you need. Some of them are displayed in other answers. The one I prefer `JOIN`s the table against itself using the column you use to group by and a condition on the columns you want to `MAX`:

```
SELECT j.id, j.title, j.department_id, j.date_created
FROM JOBS j
  LEFT JOIN jobs o USING (department_id) AND j.date_created < o.date_created
WHERE o.date_created IS NULL
```

#### How it works:

It `JOIN`s the table (aliased as `j` from "job"; this is the job you want to get in the output) against itself (aliased as `o` from "other"). Each row from `j` matches all the rows from `o` that have bigger value in `date_created` (the row from `o` was created after the one from `j`). The `LEFT JOIN` ensures all the rows from `j` are selected, even when a corresponding row is not found in `j`. For such rows from `j` a row full of `NULL`s is used instead of the row from `o`. The `WHERE` clause keeps only the rows from `j` that have `NULL` in `o.date_created`. They are the jobs from each department that have the biggest value in `date_created` (another row with a bigger value was not found).